# Condition number change in Cholesky matrix decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, condition-number, cholesky-decomposition

Give a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ that has a LDLT decomposition $A = L D L^{\top}$, why is the condition number of $A$ not less than that of matrix $D$, i.e., $\mbox{cond} (A) \geqslant \mbox{cond}(D)$?

I tried to prove this conclusion by definition, but failed. (03/06,2023)

Answer (score 1):

Since the $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ is symmetric, it can be diagonalized using an eigendecomposition $A = V \Lambda V^{\top}$, where $V$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with real eigenvalues on the diagonal. Since $A$ is also positive definite, then the smallest eigenvalue will be positive $\min_i \lambda_i = \lambda_n > 0$.

But the eigendecomposition also admits the following Rayleigh quotient result: $$\max_i \lambda_i = \lambda_1 = \max_{x \neq 0}\frac{x^{\top}Ax}{x^{\top}x} = \max_{x: \text{ }\lVert x \rVert = 1}x^{\top}Ax$$
Likewise: $$\min_i \lambda_i = \lambda_n = \min_{x \neq 0}\frac{x^{\top}Ax}{x^{\top}x} = \min_{x: \text{ }\lVert x \rVert = 1}x^{\top}Ax > 0$$
(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient)

So the eigendecomposition provides a leading eigenvector $v_1$ which maximizes the Rayleigh quotient, having value $\lambda_1$, and likewise trailing eigenvector $v_n$ which minimizes the quotient, having value $\lambda_n$.

The condition number of $A$ will of course be: $$\mbox{cond}(A) = \lambda_1 / \lambda_n$$
Since $D$ is a diagonal matrix with values $d_i$, its condition number will be: $$\mbox{cond}(D) = d_{max}/d_{min} \quad d_{max} := \max_i d_i \quad d_{min} := \min_i d_i > 0$$

$\mathsf{Statement}$: The matrix $L$ from the LDL decomposition is lower-triangular with ones on the diagonal (also called unit-lower-triangular or unitriangular), therefore: $$d_{max} \le \lambda_1 \quad d_{min} \ge \lambda_n$$

See proof of $\mathsf{Statement}$ at (*) below. Intuitively, the unit-lower-triangular matrix $L$ is not attempting to simultaneously maximize and minimize the Rayleigh quotient, in contrast to the eigendecomposition $V$, so $L$ will result in "less stretched limits".

As a result of the $\mathsf{Statement}$:
$$\lambda_1 \cdot d_{min} \ge \lambda_n \cdot d_{max}$$
$$\lambda_1 / \lambda_n \ge d_{max} / d_{min}$$
$$\mbox{cond}(A) \ge \mbox{cond}(D)$$

---

(*) Proof of $\mathsf{Statement}$:

By definition, $d_{max} := \max_i d_i = \max_i e_i^{\top} D e_i$ and $d_{min} := \min_i d_i = \min_i e_i^{\top} D e_i$ where $e_i$ is the selection vector, which has $1$ at position $i$ and zeros elsewhere, and $D$ is the diagonal matrix from the LDL decomposition. Obviously, $\lVert e_i \rVert = 1$.

From the LDL decomposition: $$A = LDL^{\top} \quad \implies \quad D = L^{-1}AL^{-\top}$$
so that $$d_i = e_i^{\top} D e_i = e_i^{\top} L^{-1}AL^{-\top} e_i$$

Note: The inverse of $L$ always exists, since $L$ is lower-triangular with ones on the diagonal (also called unit-lower-triangular or unitriangular), because it has a full set of $n$ eigenvalues which all have value $1$, so it is non-singular. (If $A$ was singular, i.e., had zero eigenvalues, then the diagonal $D$ would have had zero values.)

The matrix $L$ is lower-triangular with ones on the diagonal (also called unit-lower-triangular or unitriangular). Likewise, $L^{\top}$ is unit-upper-triangular. The following facts are known:

- The inverse of a lower triangular matrix, if it exists, is lower triangular. See p. 9 in the following link. In our case, $L$ is non-singular, so $L^{-1}$ exists.
- The inverse of an upper triangular matrix, if it exists, is upper triangular. See p. 9 in the following link.
- The inverse of a unitriangular matrix is unitriangular. See p. 16 in the following link.

Link:
[http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~ecsgaj/matrixAlgSlidesC.pdf](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Eecsgaj/matrixAlgSlidesC.pdf) by Peter J. Hammond (not affiliated with me).
See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Algebras_of_triangular_matrices.

Let's denote $x_i := L^{-\top} e_i$ so that $d_i = e_i^{\top} D e_i = x_i^{\top}Ax_i$

Observe that due to the unit-upper-triangular structure of $L^{-\top}$, the vector $x_i = L^{-\top} e_i$ will simply be the $i^{\text{th}}$ column of $L^{-\top}$, which will have a $1$ at position $i$, and can have other non-zero values at positions $1 \text{ to } i-1 \text{ (inclusive)}$. $x_i$ will have zeros at positions $i+1 \text{ to } n \text{ (inclusive)}$.

With $A = V \Lambda V^{\top} = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j v_j v_j^{\top}$ where $v_j$ is the $j^{\text{th}}$ eigenvector (the $j^{\text{th}}$ column of $V$), we have:
$$d_i = e_i^{\top} D e_i = x_i^{\top}Ax_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j (x_i^{\top}v_j)(v_j^{\top}x_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j (v_j^{\top}x_i)^2$$

For $i = 1$, $x_1 = (1, 0, \dots, 0)^{\top}$, therefore, since $V$ has orthonormal columns and also orthonormal rows, and in particular the $1^{\text{st}}$ row, then the $1^{\text{st}}$ component of vectors $\{v_j\}_{j=1}^n$ will all have magnitude $\lt 1$, resulting in weights $w_j := (v_j^{\top}x_1)^2 \lt 1$, producing $d_{max} = d_1 \le \lambda_1$.

**Note:** the assumption $d_{max} = d_1$ is valid since the LDL decomposition, both as in the original J.R. Bunch and L. Kaufman (1977) paper, and also in actual implementations, can use a permutation matrix. In the original paper this is intended for better numerical stability, but in the current proof, the availability of such a permutation allows to assume that the largest diagonal element $d_{max}$ can be assumed to be located at the first element $d_1$.

Edit 22/3/2023:

For $i = n$, as correctly observed by user @Exodd in the comments, the line of reasoning used for $i = 1$ cannot be used as it is for $i = n$. Instead, the following alternate (and hopefully correct) proof is given.

For $i = n$, since the original matrix $A$ is positive definite, it has an inverse $A^{-1}$, which is thus used with the line of reasoning presented above for $i = 1$. Specifically, $\lambda_{min}(A) = \lambda_{max}(A^{-1})$ and $d_{min}(A) = d_{max}(A^{-1})$. So using $A^{-1}$ with the reasoning for $i = 1$ will give: $d_{max}(A^{-1}) = d_1(A^{-1}) \le \lambda_1(A^{-1})$, equivalent to $d_{min}(A) = d_n(A) \ge \lambda_n(A)$ as required.

Comment: This can't be true... you can take $A,L,D$ all diagonals and find a counterexample to $d_{max}\le \lambda_1$ simply by taking $L = I*1/2$...

Comment: @Exodd $L$ is supposed to be unit-lower-triangular (1s on diagonal, zeros above it, and any values below it), so if $A$ is some diagonal matrix, consisting of $a_1, \dots, a_n$, then $L = I_n, \text{ }, D = A$. In this case: $\lambda_1 = \max_i a_i = \max_i d_i$ and $\lambda_n = \min_i a_i = \min_i d_i$, giving $\mbox{cond}(A) = \mbox{cond}(D)$. Exodd, please kindly clarify if I have misunderstood your (counter-)example.

Comment: you said "Any other linear transformation besides the eigendecomposition", not necessarily the unit lower triangular

Comment: @Exodd Ohh, I understand. You're correct! I will edit and correct my answer. I think the correct statement should be "Any other linear transformation with 1s on the diagonal".

Comment: even so, it is not clear why the Raileigh quotient should behave like that with a unit lower triangular matrix...

Comment: @Exodd The unit-lower-triangular matrix $L$ is not attempting to simultaneously maximize and minimize the Rayleigh quotient, in contrast to the eigendecomp $V$, so $L$ will result in "less stretched limits".

Comment: still not a proof. The statement that the eigendecomposition gives the better Raileigh quotient (among what transformations?) is to be proved

Comment: @Exodd I've added a proof. Please kindly review it, thanks! I admit the last line in the proof is not fully specified and clear, I'm simply not sure how to clarify it right now. Perhaps you can improve it, or perhaps suggest something. Thanks

Comment: "the only way for any of the $d_i$ to equal a specific $x_j$ is for the vector $x_i$ to be equal (up to sign) to $v_j$" 
This is false. This is not the only way at all. For example, if the eigenvalues are $1,2,3$ you can obtain $2$ as the average of $1,3$ or also as $2/3$ of $3$, or as double of $1$. In fact $x_i^Tv_j$ can be greater than 1 and their sum can be any

Comment: also, the fact that the weights $w_j$ are less than 1 does not imply that $\sum_j\lambda_jw_j<\lambda_{max}$. For that you have to prove that the weights $w_j$ are sub-convex.

Comment: Gave an alternate and hopefully correct proof of the d_{min} case, i.e., for i = n.